# Large excretion of sap from Austrian Pine

Tags: pines, sap

I noticed a large clump of sap in my lawn, and determined that it came from the Austrian pine tree nearby. (I didn't know what it was at first because of the color, but it had a strong pine odor). A 3-4 inch diameter branch was cut off about 10 years ago, and this sap came from that stub.

[image: sap that fell from tree]

I've never seen anything like this. Is the tree unhealthy/dying? I haven't noticed anything else that leads me to believe the tree is unhealthy.

Comment: Look for a canker or similar in the area above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  You do not have anything to worry about. The vascular system is working.  Pines are full of sap.  Maples full of syrup.  Milkweed full of milky sap.  Unless you see any other signs that indicate poor health, your tree will be just fine.  Check for insect infestations.  I think all is well...